# QCoreApplication destructor is not called

Tags: c++, c, qt

I have an application that derived from `QCoreApplication` class and has a child thread member. When I delete the app object it someimes deletes sometimes not.

```
class My_class :public QCoreApplication{
   private: 
   My_object* obj;
   QThread *th;
   public:
   My_class(){
      obj=new My_object();
      th= new QThread();
      obj->movetoThread(th);  // so it starts to run   
   }  
   ~My_class(){
      delete obj;       
      cout<<" App Destructor called"<<endl;
      }

   static void exit_(){quit();}        
 };

 // So in main I suddenly close my application and i want to exit and delete obj;
  int main()
  {
      My_class app;

      signal(SIGTERM,&app.exit_); 
      signal(SIGINT,&app.exit_); 
      signal(SIGBREAK,&app.exit_); 
      return app.exec();
  }
  // The obj destructor is;
  ~My_object::My_object(){cout<<"Object dest called"<<endl;}
  // The output of my program always writes "Object dest called"
  //But sometimes writes " App Destructor called".
```

So my program always enters the `destructpr` of the obj but sometimes it enters app destructor and sometimes not. How can it be achievable?

Comment: I think it really points out how **very important** it is to post complete, self-contained, compileable code. That way we won't have to waste time on silly mistakes like that.

Comment: @KubaOber yes you are right

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in using a post routine for app destruction documented [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qcoreapplication.html#qAddPostRoutine).

In this case, you could register a post routine to cleanup all the threads that you store in a given collection:

```
 QList<QThread*> myThreads;
 static void cleanup_threads()
 {
     foreach (QThread thread, myThreads) {
         // cleanup the thread and delete it
     }
 }

 int main(int argc, char **argv) {
     QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);
     qAddPostRoutine(cleanup_threads);

     // setup signal handlers
     // create threads
     return app.exec();
 }
```

This approach can be pretty dangerous unless you know exactly what you're doing. The preferred approach would be to create another class, derived from QObject, that you would parent your threads to:

```
class MyThreadManager : public QObject {
    MyThreadManager(QObject *parent = 0) 
        : QObject(parent) 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
            MyThread *thread = new MyThread(this);
            // configure the thread object
            thread->start();

            // maybe add it to a local collection for later access: 
            // m_threads.append(thread);
        }
    }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);
    // setup signal handlers
    MyThreadManager manager;
    return app.exec();
}
```

This way, all of your threads are parented to the same object that is cleaned up by the parent's QObjectCleanupHandler upon destruction.

Comment: This is a rather convoluted way to go about it.

Comment: Mind you @KubaOber, I was working with the original code posted. He seems to want to keep track of threads, as well as the objects associated with those threads. It's not necessarily a bad idea to maintain that in a helper class. Having said that, I guess I consider your comment to my response to be negative without justification, and thus not very helpful

Comment: The problem with the original code is rather simple and doesn't require extensive design changes. There's a race/unprotected cross-thread access of an object, that's all.

Answer (score 0):

You move the `obj` to another thread:

```
My_class(){
  obj=new My_object();
  th= new QThread();
  obj->movetoThread(th);  // so it starts to run   
}
```

A `QObject` can only be deleted from its thread, if it has one. Thus, this code is wrong:

```
~My_class() {
   // You can't delete `obj` from a thread other than `th`!
   delete obj;       
   cout<<" App Destructor called"<<endl;
}
```

What you must do is to first finish the thread, and only then delete the object:

```
~My_class() {
  th->quit();
  th->wait();
  delete th;
  Q_ASSERT(obj->thread() == NULL); // thus it's safe to delete obj now!
  delete obj;
}
```

This can be accomplished automatically. There's no reason that I see that you should keep the thread and the object on the heap. It's a premature pessimization. If you intend to lazy-construct the object and its thread upon first use, then you should use a smart pointer: `QScopedPointer` (or `std::unique_ptr`, but **not** `std::auto_ptr`).

```
class Thread : public QThread {
  using QThread::run; // It's a final class
public:
  explicit Thread(QObject * parent = 0) : QThread(parent) {}
  ~Thread() { quit(); wait(); }
}

class My_Class : public QCoreApplication{
  My_Object m_obj;
  Thread m_thread; // Must be declared after any objects that live in it.
public:
  My_Class(){
    m_obj.moveToThread(&m_thread);
    m_thread.start(); 
  }  
  static void exit_() { quit(); }        
};
```

This works because `m_thread` will be destructed before `m_obj`. You can and should utilize the C++ compiler to generate the correct code for you. After all, the compiler will always get it right.